# Как передать указатель на объект в оконную процедуру (колбэк)?

Tags: c, winapi, callback

Требуется использовать объявленный в main экземпляр класса в оконном колбеке:
 `long __stdcall WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);`
Как передать в эту функцию указатель если и WPARAM, и LPARAM уже "заняты" своим функционалом?

Comment: Set / GetWindowLongPtr с флагом GWLP_USERDATA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `SetWindowLongPtr` + `GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)`
`SetWindowLongPtr` принято вызывать в обработчике WM_CREATE, передавать через поле `CREATESTRUCT::lpCreateParams`.

2) `SetProp(hwnd, "unique str", (HANDLE)data)` + `GetProp`
(data может иметь любое значение, это не обязательно хендл; уникальный идентификатор может быть глобальным атомом)

3) Сгенерировать свою функцию-обертку, как это сделано в WTL.
Т.е. например для x86-32 выделить память и записать туда `mov ecx, this / jmp func`.

Comment: А вот по пункту 1... Как в `WM_CREATE` передать указатель того, что объявлено в `main` и вызвать `SetWindowLongPtr`? Ведь это уже оконная процедура.

Comment: В общем так и не удалось инициализировать в WM_CREATE используя 1-й метод - передаётся не понятно что. Сделал по 2 способу, вызывая SetPropA после создания окна. Всё работает